# Rename PC in Win 10 via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, rename

A VBScript we use to enter a computer name while configuring new systems that works fine in Windows 7 seems to not do anything in Windows 10. Are there any changes I can make to allow this to work in Windows 10?

```
Function NewPrep
  Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\ECSUser\AppData\Local\Marlin\ECSConfiguration.xml")

  Set nNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//NewDataSet/GlobalSettings/SerialNum")

  nNode.Text = ""
  Do While nNode.Text = ""
    nNode.Text = InputBox("Enter the ECS PC Serial Number:", "ECSNewPrep")
  Loop

  strResult = xmldoc.Save("C:\Users\ECSUser\AppData\Local\Marlin\ECSConfiguration.xml")

  Do While Name = ""
    Name = InputBox("Enter the Computer Name:", "ECSNewPrep")
  Loop
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:root\cimv2")
  For Each objComputer In objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_ComputerSystem")
    Return = objComputer.Rename(Name)
  Next

  If intCellular = vbYes Then
    'Cellular - Commented out 6/18/2015 - MB
    AV
  End If

  If intAV = vbYes Then
    AV
  End If

  Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
  Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
  strComputer = "."
  Set Stdout = WScript.StdOut

  Set oReg = GetObject ("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
             strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "AppEvents\Schemes", strValueName, ".None"
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_USERS, ".Default\Control Panel\Keyboard", "InitialKeyboardIndicators", 0

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If (objFSO.FolderExists("C:\ECS\AV")) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFolder "C:\ECS\AV"
  End If
  Set objFSO = Nothing

  Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  sRegFile = "C:\Windows\system32\postsysprep.reg"
  objShell.Run "regedt32.exe /s""sRegFile""", 0, True
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""ECSManager"" dir=in action=allow program=""c:\ecs\ecsmanager\csmanager.exe"" enable=yes"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""ECSAlert"" dir=in action=allow program=""c:\ecs\ecsAlert\ecsAlert.exe"" enable=yes"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""ECSMonitor"" dir=in action=allow program=""C:\ECS\ECSMonitor\ECSMonitor.exe"" enable=yes"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""ECSSoftwareAutoUpdater"" dir=in action=allow program=""c:\ecs\ecssoftwareautoupdater\ecssoftwareautoupdater.exe"" enable=yes"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""ECSConfig"" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=11337"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request"" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=""remote desktop"" new enable=Yes"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=""remote administration"" new enable=yes"
  objShell.Run "CMD /c powercfg -setactive 7dba7c8d-b82a-4f3e-9bd3-25ef4c6369ca"
  objShell.Run "NET USER administrator /active:yes"
  objShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ato", 0, True
  objShell.Run "control.exe TimeDate.cpl"

  set objAutoUpdate = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
  set objSettings = objAutoUpdate.Settings

  objSettings.NotificationLevel = 4
  objSettings.Save

  MsgBox "PC will now reboot", , "ECSNewPrep"

  objShell.Run "shutdown -r -t 00"
End Function

Function Cellular
  strComputer = "."
  Do While strValue = ""
    strValue = InputBox("Enter the Cellular MAC:", "ECSNewPrep")
  Loop
  Set Stdout = WScript.StdOut

  Set oReg = GetObject ("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
             strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0010", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0011", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0024", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0013", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0014", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0015", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0016", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0017", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0018", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0019", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0020", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0021", "NetworkAddress", strValue
  oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0022", "NetworkAddress", strValue

  MsgBox "Adding MAC To Registry", , "ECSNewPrep"
End Function

Function AV
  Set objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If (objFSO.FolderExists("C:\ECS\AV")) Then
    strComputer = "."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strcomputer & "\root\cimv2")
    objWMIService.Create "C:\ecs\AV\Setup.exe", null, null, intProcessID

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colMonitoredProcesses = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
      ("Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'")

    Do Until i = 1
      Set objLatestProcess = colMonitoredProcesses.NextEvent
      If objLatestProcess.TargetInstance.ProcessID = intProcessID Then
        i = 1
      End If
    Loop
  Else
    MsgBox "AV Installer Missing from C:\ECS\AV", , "ECSNewPrep"
  End If
End Function

intCellular = MsgBox("Is this PC for a Cellular Install?", vbYesNo, "ECSNewPrep")

If intCellular = vbNo Then
  intAV = MsgBox("Does this PC require AV?", vbYesNo, "ECSNewPrep")
End If

NewPrep
```

Comment: What is the value of `Return` after the rename operation? Are you running this as an administrator? Did you reboot?

Comment: I am not a coder and simply trying to repair something someone else wrote a long time ago that has worked until Windows 10. I will post the full script and hope that helps answer your question. 

I can say it does reboot and does not change the PC name after.

Comment: I believe you need to [include a username and password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393056(v=vs.85).aspx) for an administrative account, so this line: `Return = objComputer.Rename(Name)` should be something like `Return = objComputer.Rename(Name, Password, Username)`